# C++ Invalid entry error detector for menu program

Tags: c++

I am almost done building a menu that serves multiple purposes for a final project. It's built with voids, and structured like this...

```
 do
  {

    menu (selection);

    if (selection == 1)
    {
        system("CLS");
        Program1();
        system("Pause");
    }

    if (selection == 2)
    {
        system ("CLS");
        Program2();
        system("Pause");
    }
```

etc...

The last thing the menu needs is an error detector. The menu has options 1-5, so if someone were to enter 6, it would read "Invalid Entry", and then ask the user if they would like to re-enter the menu. The problem I'm getting is figuring out how to do it. If I have it set to a void, like "void Invalid_Entry();" it wont let me terminate the program within the void. If I just have it set as..

"else

{
cout << "invalid entry" << endl;

cout << "try again? (Y/N)" << endl;

cin >> answer;"

}

..I can terminate the program with return 0;, but I can't find a way to redirect it back to the menu when the user would answer "Y". Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool flag combined with a while loop.

```
bool var_continue = false;
while (var_continue) {
    menu(selection);
    switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            system("CLS");
            Program1();
            system("Pause");
            break;
        case 2:
            system("CLS");
            Program2();
            system("Pause");
            break;
        default:
            cout << "invalid entry" <<endl;
            cout << "try again? (Y/N)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            var_continue = (answer == "Y");
    }
}
```